# Is the places API not able to retrieve specific places?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm building an app that I'd like to integrate with the Places API. It is built on a constrained list of places that I will be adding and allowing users to "bump" as well see/add reviews and photos, etc. I'm looking for a way to add those places and then retrieve them without seeing anything outside of my constrained list. The documentation indicates that IDs or references are not stable, nor can I add a unique place type. Does that mean my design is simply impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Google Places Video demonstration](http://youtu.be/JCgTAWXwjOk?t=19m23s) you can add and retrieve custom places using `"types": ["other"]` as this type is not used for any places in our data.

Comment: Won't that return anything anyone has added as "other"? Or is it unique to my API key?

Comment: Awesome. I gather that you're a member of the Places dev team? Maybe this tidbit should be explicit in the docs.